# ImageMagick: how to draw two strings with different size over image?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I want to draw a rectangle with two strings in it. I want the first string to be 15pt size (its a number), second to be 10pt size (the label). It's easy to draw single string with one size to the rectangle, I do it like this:

```
$image = new Imagick('someimage.png');
$draw = new ImagickDraw;
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$draw->setfont(__DIR__ . DS . 'TREBUCBD.TTF');
$draw->setfontsize(15);
$draw->annotation(0, 0, '50 points');
$image->drawImage($draw);
```

The idea here is to have "50" in "50 points" to be big.

I tried to do a $draw->push() to push the current settings to the stack then set the font size and annotation again but then the two strings overlap. I've been trying to do this for hours. Any help is very appreciated!

The above implementation is in PHP but probably I will manage to do it even by example that shows it with command line ImageMagick usage.

edit: I've started a bounty that I will award for a solution implemented in PHP.

Comment: How about http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-annotateimage.php? Looks like this is what you want. There a full example on the page as well.

Comment: DrColossos, that produces the very same result - it would produce text string with given font and size but I want part of that string to be bigger then the rest and in the same time the 2 parts together to be centered as if they were one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add enough space before "points" and after the "50" so you align them nicely:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick('test.png');
$draw = new ImagickDraw;
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$draw->setfontsize(30);
$draw->annotation(0, 0, '50         ');
$image->drawImage($draw);

$draw = new ImagickDraw;
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$draw->setfontsize(15);
$draw->annotation(0, 0, '      points');
$image->drawImage($draw);

file_put_contents('test.png', $image->getImageBlob());
?>
```

Comment: This is a solution, basically I make them overlap and write them. But in the same time I have to again "calculate" how many spaces to have.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [+append](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#append) option to make two different text labels joined horizontally (`-append` - vertically):

```
convert -background grey -pointsize 15 -fill black label:abc \
        -pointsize 10 -fill red label:cdefgh -gravity South +append test.png
```

This code actually produces two images sized exactly to fit font (since there's no explicit size specified), and then this two images are horizontally appended together:

[image]

Once again: the size of this image is calculated automatically to fit your labels. You can use `Imagick::labelImage` and `Imagick::appendImages` functions to achieve this. (To make image without background, you can specify `-backround transparent`, e.g. via `Imagick::setBackgroundColor`)

After that, resulting image with labels can be composed with anything you want.

Comment: This is nice, though I can not find a way to do it with the PHP ImageMagick wrapper.

Comment: `Imagick::appendImages`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-appendimages.php

Comment: No, it appends different images together but I want to tell it <<draw me the string "51 points" centered in rectangle of size 100x50, "51" having font size 15pt, and "pints" having font size 11px>>. If I draw and append two different images, I have to do calculations myself, because it might look OK for "51 points" but if its "10051 points" the center would move.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want. What does "the center would move" mean? Ok, you've got image, constructed from two strings with different pointsize, then you center it in rectangle of size 100x50. It's obvious that if for strings with different length ("51 points" and "100500 points") its x coord after centering will be different. Isn't that the behaviuor you asked for?

Comment: I might not understand you as well but with append image I can not construct one image of 100x50 size with the 2 different strings in it, I have to construct 2 different images and glue them together and I have to do the size calculations of each of those images myself. I should tell the image that holds the big integer part of the string (105150) to be of NNxNN pixels and the small part (points) to be of NNxNN pixels, is that not correct? I will experiment more tomorrow and will confirm!

Comment: Using the Imagick object I seem to be not able to create image, annotate it with text and then append them together after big number of different tries :(