# Add space between each word in multi-colored text image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to produce multi-colored text image with Imagemagick and PHP. The following code works, but I cannot insert a space after each word. I have tried various settings, nothing is working. Should I use annotate or draw text command instead of label? Label seems to be simple to use here.

```
$file = 'font.ttf'; 

$command = "convert -background white -fill black -font $file -pointsize 80 -density 90 label:New  -fill black -font $file -pointsize 80 -density 90 label:Here -fill red -font $file -pointsize 80 -density 90 label:? +append $multi-color-text.png"; 

exec($command);
```

Update: Solution

Remarks: Spaces do not work in command line. So, I need to escape double quotes with a forward slash.

This has worked:

```
$command = "convert -background white -fill black -font $file -pointsize 80 -density 90 label:\"New \"  -fill black -font $file -pointsize 80 -density 90 label:\"Here \" -fill red -font $file -pointsize 80 -density 90 label:? +append $multi-color-text.png";
```

Thank you all, especially Fred!

Comment: try using `\n`. Not 100% sure about it, but you can try it. Or concatenating `"convert ... code... . " " . etc.`

Comment: Hi Fred, I need all those words in a single line. '\n' will create multi-line I think.

Comment: I had a feeling about that. I edited my comment above to try and concatenate. I.e. `"convert . " " . etc` type of thing.

Comment: Is `$multi-color-text` supposed to be a variable?

Comment: @Phellipe, $multi-color-text is a variable.

Comment: which one in there is the "word" you want to have spaces in? If it's coming from a variable, you can always do `$var = "This is " . "  " . " text " . $other_var;` which is a variance of the example I left you above.

Comment: Here, see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221686/imagemagick-how-to-draw-two-strings-with-different-size-over-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756110/imagemagick-creating-thumbnail I think you will find your answer in one or both of those. Seems like you will have to annotate. I think the 2nd one is the solution.

Comment: Hi Fred, you saved my day. Your link worked. Spaces does not work in command line. What a stupid I am. I will update my post soon.

Comment: You might try using -interword-spacing to change the space between words.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems like it would be better to use `-annotate` once you want to insert multiple texts instead of using `-label`.

Example of use of `-annotate`: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#gravity_text

Comment: *"Have you tried"* answers are better off as comments, of which that I have left the OP under their question already, containing Q&A's using annotate.

Comment: Indeed @Fred-ii-, I've rewritten the answer. I hadn't seen your comment.

Comment: @Phellipe, you and Fred also suggested to use -annotate here. Will use it.

Comment: No problem Phellipe. @AnayBose consider accepting his answer then, in order to close the question and mark it as solved, *cheers*